# How to keep log messages to a file in JCShell?

Tags: smartcard, javacard, jcop, gpshell

I am executing some commands in JCShell (init-update, auth-ext, etc) to communicate with a SmartCard. I would like to address all those log messages to a file, so then I could manipulate them.

What is the command/method to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer:

- Create a file in  called e.g. log.txt
- In JCShell: `> 3 '<path>\log.txt'`

That's all! From now all messages showed in JCShell terminal will be redirected to log.txt file too.

Comment: Thanks. It saves the output message of the command, but not the command. Do you know how to source this from `jcshell.rc`?